# Numbers, Racked Up

Tags: knowledge, sequence

What does this list of numbers represent?

> 16
> 5
> 0
> 3
> 11
> 2
> 2
> 5
> 5
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 7
> 4
> 14
> 4
> 1
> 1
> 3
> 4
> 6
> 0
> 2
> 2
> 3
> 1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Took a bit of sherlocking, but I think I got it.

There are 26 numbers, some of them zero, and there are several duplicates. Surely this must then be

> A [histogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram) of letters in a 26-letter alphabet.

The largest numbers are at positions 1,5, and 15, corresponding to

> the letters A and E (expected in English text) and O (common, but not really expected in competition for being the most abundant letter). U seems to be a bit overrepresented too. Still, it's very likely going to be English with some twist that makes vowels more common, like some often repeated name with a lot of vowels, or something else along those lines.

Adding up all the numbers gives 107, which turns out to be a sufficient clue, because when we delve deep into the [knowledge](/questions/tagged/knowledge) tag, we find out that

> there are exactly 107 valid two-letter words in Scrabble.

This is perfect, since that's exactly the kind of "English, but slightly unusual" we were looking for. And indeed

> The initial letters of [all the Scrabble-valid two-letter words](https://www.trussel.com/scrabble/2words.htm) do follow this exact distribution. (At least they do now, after OP fixed the tiny mistake in the original question.)

This also explains the observed vowel prevalence: there's a hard cap on the maximum number assignable to any consonant.

As further confirmation that we got it, the title tells us that the question was indeed about numbers you rack up before using.

Comment: I feel you're very close, but if these are in the usual order shouldn't WE (for one) be represented here?

Comment: Good point. Looks like OP has swapped V and W. All the others match.

Comment: Where's CH, eh?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel in the Alps, probably. Not on the list in any case.

Comment: It seems I can't make a puzzle without making a mistake.  I checked the list thoroughly, but didn't check the alphabet!